# Convert String value into BigDecimal and sort them in descending order and then print them

Tags: java, string, sorting, bigdecimal

**here is my code but it is not taking a string as it is in BigDecimal variable**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BigDesimal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        String[] s = new String[n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
            s[i] = in.next();
        }
        in.close();

        BigDecimal max, min;
        for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
            for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
                max = (new BigDecimal(s[i])).max(new BigDecimal(s[j]));
                min = (new BigDecimal(s[i])).min(new BigDecimal(s[j]));
                s[i] = max.toString();
                s[j] = min.toString();
                 
                
            }
        }
         

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));

    }

}
```

I run this program for the following input:
*9

-100,
50,
0,
56.6,
90,
0.12,
.12,
02.34,
000.000*

And the output is:
*[90, 56.6, 50, 2.34, 0.12, 0.12, 0, 0, -100]*

Comment: What is the question? What is the problem? Do you want the array s to be an array of BigDecimals?

Comment: BigDecimal implements Comparable, so this handy static method should work: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)

Comment: here is the link of the problem.      https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-bigdecimal/problem

Answer (score 1):

You can change your inner loop body to this:

```
String si = s[i], sj = s[j];
if (new BigDecimal(si).compareTo(new BigDecimal(sj)) < 0) {
    s[i] = sj;
    s[j] = si;
}
```

You don't need to store the result from converted big decimals back into the array, but use them only for comparison.

For the input:

```
9, -100, 50, 0, 56.6, 90, 0.12, .12, 02.34, 000.000
```

I get back:

```
90, 56.6, 50, 9, 02.34, .12, 0.12, 0, 000.000, -100
```

## [DEMO](https://ideone.com/x5jvZb)

And if you don't work with massive big numbers, normal `double`s should suffice:

```
if(Double.parseDouble(si) < Double.parseDouble(sj))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (untested):

```
        List<String> sortedNumberStrings = Arrays.stream(numberStrings)
                .map(NumberString::new)
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                .map(NumberString::getStringValue)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(sortedNumberStrings);



private static class NumberString implements Comparable<NumberString> {

        private final String stringValue;
        private final BigDecimal bigDecimalValue;

        NumberString(String stringValue) {

            this.stringValue = stringValue;
            this.bigDecimalValue = new BigDecimal(stringValue);
        }

        public String getStringValue() {
            return stringValue;
        }

        public BigDecimal getBigDecimalValue() {
            return bigDecimalValue;
        }

        private static final Comparator<NumberString> NATURAL_ORDER_COMPARATOR =
                Comparator.comparing(NumberString::getBigDecimalValue) // sort by value
                        .thenComparing(NumberString::getStringValue); // sort lexically

        @Override
        public int compareTo(NumberString other) {
            return NATURAL_ORDER_COMPARATOR.compare(this, other);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(stringValue, bigDecimalValue);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) {
                return true;
            }
            if (!(o instanceof NumberString)) {
                return false;
            }
            NumberString that = (NumberString) o;
            return Objects.equals(stringValue, that.stringValue) &&
                    Objects.equals(bigDecimalValue, that.bigDecimalValue);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return stringValue;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What the author may seek is following as the solution.

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
        if (new BigDecimal(s[j]).compareTo(new BigDecimal(s[j + 1])) < 0) {
            String temp = s[j];
            s[j] = s[j + 1];
            s[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

What this change from the @Lino's answer is the order of `0.12` and `.12`

This gives following output and this should be the output according to the [problem link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-bigdecimal/problem) that the author has shared.

`90  56.6    50  02.34   0.12    .12     0   000.000 -100`

Answer (score 0):

First thing to understand is that we need to maintain the input string data to printed in same format in output e.g. 0.12 and .12 are to be printed in same format as in the input. If we just do BigDecimal based comparison then input data format will be lost and .12 becomes 0.12. Hence to have this format, we could have the data stored in a Pair like format where one data is used to BigDecimal comparison while other data is used for keeping the original format.

Using Java 8, I came up with below solution:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    //Input
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    String [][] s=new String[n][2];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        s[i][0]=sc.next(); // to be used for BigDecimal comparison
        s[i][1]=s[i][0];   // to be used for printing in original format
    }
    sc.close();

    Arrays.stream(s)
            .sorted((o1, o2) -> new BigDecimal(o2[0]).compareTo(new BigDecimal(o1[0])))
            .forEach(o -> System.out.println(o[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

To get an ascending list of values you can use a `List` and the `List.sort` method.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] strings = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
    List<BigDecimal> values = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String string : strings)
        values.add(new BigDecimal(string));
    values.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());
    System.out.println(values);
}
```

Output

```
[-100, 0, 0.000, 0.12, 0.12, 2.34, 50, 56.6, 90]
```